# Flutter Web: Browser Refresh Button restarts app from splash

Tags: flutter, dart

> I am developing the flutter web app, if user refresh the browser page
> from browser button or from url, app starts from start. app shows
> splash and shows the login page. I want to handle the scenario like if
> user click on refresh the button it should refresh the state of
> current widget.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

a work around suggest :
you can store the current route with its state and the variables so when splash screen run check if there is a current rout to go in.

Comment: is there any automated mechanism that can be integrated for this?

Comment: or any implementation details you can share?

Comment: actually it is just an idea, I don't have a current implement for it, but it is simple to apply by using any state management.